# How to conditionally format whole row depending on ONLY ONE cell value?

Tags: excel, formatting

Please forgive my inexperience if this is a simply-answered question, but amidst all my Googling I just cannot seem to figure this out. I have a self-made "budget" sheet of sorts, in which I set a goal to spend, for example, $600 this month. Starting out, this means that I am allowed to spend 600/31 or 600/30 daily, depending on how many days are in the current month. As I spend throughout the month, I run a formula to calculate how the daily spending allowance changes depending on the days of the month with this formula:

```
=A37/(EOMONTH(TODAY(),0)-TODAY())
```

Where cell **A37** is my 600/31 or 600/30. I simply want to know how to format a row - containing what I've spent for the whole day - and color it red depending on **ONLY THIS ONE CELL'S VALUE**. Right now, I have the row colored red if the values are lesser than -19.35, which is -600/31, but I want the format to trigger depending on the running calculated cell rather than a number defined by me. I have tried "lesser than" **$C44**, "lesser than" **$C$44**, and even "lesser than" **insert formula above**. Any further ideas? Thank you very much in advance!

An example can be seen here: https://i.stack.imgur.com/jukQH.jpg, where "Food/Other Allow." keeps track of the remaining I can spend taken from the original $600. I am formatting **Row 33**, coloring them red if they are **lesser than -19.35**.

Comment: could you post a picture of what you are trying to to ?

Comment: Apologies, I would have added a picture into the post itself, but I don't have enough reputation points. I've added an imgur link instead.

Comment: `Formatting` > `Use formatting to determine which cells to format` `=C$33>$C$44` You can use that for the range ($C$2:$ZZ$33) and it will highlight any spending item that's contributed to overspending. I personally would *name* the daily spending norm cell (i.e. C44).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Setting up your $ left as:

```
=600-SUM(C33:ZZ33)
```

And your rolling allowance as

```
=A37/(EOMONTH(TODAY(),0)-TODAY())
```

Like you said, definitely works if you select your cells and go to conditional formatting, highlight, then less than $C$44, picture attached (different cell locations) for proof. Are you sure you have automatic calculations enabled?

[image]

Comment: You are completely correct, and after replicating this on Excel 2013 I can confirm it is working. I keep my budget on my Google Docs and access it through Google Sheets, which must be where the problem lies. I replicated your steps there, and was unable to see any results. I feel a little ridiculous for not downloading a local copy and trying it there first, but thank you for your insight!